# XamlParseException when deserializing xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I wouldnt ask but i have no idea whats wrong again. Iv saved vehicles to an xml file and when the user opens the program i want to deserialize.when i run it i get this on the final line in the load method

```
   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' {"'The invocation of the constructor on type 'SD2CW2.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.'}
```

these are my load/save methods

```
    private void Load()
    {

        XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Vechicle));

        // Reading a file requires a FileStream.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath);
        Vechicle = ((List<Vechicle>)SerializerObj.Deserialize(fs));
    }
    //Save the objects
    private void Save()
    {
        // Create a new file stream to write the serialized object to a file
        TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(filepath);

        Type [] extraTypes= new Type[2];
        extraTypes[0] = typeof(Tour);
        extraTypes[1] = typeof(Vechicle);
        // Create a new XmlSerializer instance with the type of List<Journey> and my addition types
        XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Journey>),extraTypes);

        //serialising my journey list
        SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream,Journey);
        SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Vechicle>));
        //serialising my vechicle list
        SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, Vechicle);
        // Cleanup
        WriteFileStream.Close();
    }
```

this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfJourney xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" /><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfVechicle xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Vechicle>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Registration>1</Registration>
  </Vechicle>
  <Vechicle>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Registration>2</Registration>
  </Vechicle>
  <Vechicle>
<Id>3</Id>
<Registration>3</Registration>
```

Comment: Why are you serializing two different objects (Journey,  Vehicle) to the same file? Only one of these Serialize operations is followed by a flush to disk; this may be the cause of the missing tags mentioned in the @splrs answer.

Comment: @groverboy iv changed it so it serialize's to two xml files the tags are now correct but im still unable to load.

Comment: If the tags were incorrect as mentioned in the @splrs answer then you should accept that answer. If you are still unable to load,  create a new question and post your updated code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the entire XML file? Because it's incomplete.

If so, add

```
</Vechicle>
</ArrayOfVechicle>
</ArrayOfJourney>
```

So you've at least got a well-formed XML document to start with.